# How to connect office PC microphone to home Pc microphone?

Tags: windows, audio, remote-desktop, remote-access, microphone

I am working from home because of the covid situation. I connect my office PC and start working from here but the problem is when I call to our customer using our call software in office pc. The customers do not hear me.

We tried windows RDP but it was too slow and it gets stuck after few minutes of working. Our Administrator troubleshoots it and found out its problem from ISP and ISP agreed, n say we r working on it.

I went for 3rd party software such as Ammy, AnyDesktop and Teamviewer but none of them support to connecting office microphone to my home laptop mic. So I can speak to customers and they are able to hear me.I can hear them even I can hear sound input from my office pc microphone. Any suggestion?
I am using windows 10 and also installed on office PC.

Answer (score 1):

One option is looking in call software settings. There's usually an option to pick which audio input source to use, and your laptop microphone can sometimes be available as a virtual device you can choose, depending on which remote access technology you use and what kind of call software you have.

However, this is unlikely to be a good solution, because of the extra latency involved. Everything you say will end up delayed. This is true no matter what you do for a remote access solution. There's already latency introduced for the VoIP call service, but the software can usually account for and hide it so some degree. Adding an additional hop through the internet will likely be more than the software can manage, and things will end up out of sync or delayed. It won't be a good experience on either end of the line.

A better solution is getting your IT people to help you install the call software on your laptop.

Comment: He is not that technical skillful. He recommended RDP but ISP took ages to sort it out. Now he said all 3rd party remote desktop softwares does not support this feature. which i don't agree with and search of my own now.

Comment: He's mostly right. There probably is a way to make this work via a remote connection, but even then _it can never provide a good experience_, because of the increased latency. Much better to get the call software onto your own machine.

Comment: Our server works only on local network, its not live. I really appreciate your time and interest. Don't you know any software which can support it now I tried Aplemix aswell but its does not work as well. You can voice chat with the remote computer but not use MIC remotely. I am ready to pay for it. would you pls let me know if there is any forum where i can find any solution or solution provider. regards

Comment: You may need to get a VPN solution working, then, so you can connect from the home computer into the work network.